# ML/ Neural Networks - Predict a movement Help Needed

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, neural-network, brain.js

Hi I need an advice on how to achieve this, I got a lot of data of my clients ( sign in and sign-out, age, location) , as well the frequency they use my product, i wanted to test if i could predict whenever a new client as a high probability of signning out based on there frequency and dates of registration, is something like this possible with brain.js or AWS ?

Any details on how could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS **sagemaker** to do almost any ML algorithms (it is basically a managed jupyther notebook in the cloud).

For your problem, I would suggest,

1. Put your data into an s3 bucket ([useful examples here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-s3.html))
2. Create a JN instance and connect to s3 (using boto3)
3. Create new features that could be predictive of your target (frequency of shopping, latency, etc.)
4. Train/test your problem (which seems like binary classification for your case)
5. Deploy the trained model into production ([read more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-hosting.html))